# writing array values ​to an object

Tags: javascript

I have the code

```
const walk = ['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']
let object ={}

walk.filter(elem=>elem =='n').reduce((acc,item)=>{
    object["north"] = ++acc
    return acc++
},0)

walk.filter(elem=>elem =='s').reduce((acc,item)=>{
    object["south"] = ++acc
    return acc++
},0)
```

here I iterate through the array and write the direction of movement to the object. Is it possible to somehow simplify the expressions? for example use 1 reduce. It seems to me that it can be done without two filter and reduce, but I don’t quite understand how. I write this data into an object, with the number of times it turns in a certain direction

you can simply iterate through forEach, but I wanted to practice reduce, although it’s not relevant here

Comment: You would do the check for `s` or `n` inside the reduce function and then increment the counter for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the direction as ke for getting a total for every direction.

```js
const
    walk = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's'],
    result = walk.reduce((r, direction) => {
        r[direction] = (r[direction] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const walk = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's'];
let object = {};

object = walk.reduce((acc, direction) => {
    if (direction === 'n') {
        acc["north"] = (acc["north"] || 0) + 1;
    } else if (direction === 's') {
        acc["south"] = (acc["south"] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(object);
```

Here, the reduce function iterates through the walk array, and for each direction encountered, it updates the object with the count of that direction. The acc (accumulator) starts as an empty object {}. If the direction is 'n', it increments the "north" count in the object, and if the direction is 's', it increments the "south" count.

This way, you achieve the same result with a single reduce operation and avoid the need for separate filter and reduce operations.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask (acc["north"] || 0) Does it check if the key exists and if it doesn’t, returns 0? Then we add 1 to it
And if there is a key, then we get it and add 1?

Comment: yes. Initilally, when acc["north"] does not exist, it performs 0 + 1 = 1 and assigns 1 to  acc["north"].

After that each time it will increase it's previous value by 1

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `.reduce` callback you check for the value of the current item
and assign accordingly to the accumulator.

In the second parameter of `.reduce` we pass the initial value
of the accumulator to start at 0 each direction.

```js
const directions = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's']

const object = directions.reduce((acc, direction) => {
  switch (direction) {
    case 'n':
      acc.north++
    break

    case 's':
      acc.south++
    break
  }

  return acc
}, {north: 0, south: 0})

console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const walk = ['n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']

const object = walk.reduce((acc, item) => ({
  north: item === 'n' ? acc.north + 1 : acc.north,
  south: item === 's' ? acc.south + 1 : acc.south,
}), {north: 0, south: 0})

console.log(object)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to get. Very smart answer